# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library json.so wrong architecture

Tags: php, json, zend-server, zend-server-ce

I'm using laravel and thus require the command line to run artisan commands.

When doing so, php gives me the following errors:

```
"Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/json.so' - dlopen(/usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/json.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/json.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0"
```

When checking "which php" it points to the right version (of zend server) as I've added that to my path variable.

```
which php
/usr/local/zend/bin/php
```

Any idea what can be done to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, what I did was the following:

edit /usr/local/zend/etc/conf.d/json.ini and comment out the line that loads the json.so file

PHP doesn't throw errors at that point.

JSON support still seems enabled as far as I can see.

```
php -i | grep "json support"
json support => enabled
```